# Fonts on OpenJDK vs. Sun JDK 1.6 [Linux Platform]

Tags: fonts, java

I noticed that the Fonts on OpenJDK vs. Sun JDK look different.  Java JDK has a better font set that accompanies it.  Does anyone know what package the 'font' is and how I can have it on OpenJDK installations?

Thanks

Comment: You probably mean "Sun JDK" (or "Oracle JDK") instead of "Java JDK".

Answer (score 3):

It's an issue related to anti-aliasing when rendering Swing based GUIs. Anti-aliasing comes enabled by default with Oracle JDK, and for some reasons (that I never wanted to investigate) anti-aliasing is not enabled in OpenJDK.

You can enable anti-aliasing support with your current OpenJDK installation by adding this instruction to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on"
```

Good luck!